# This question has been deleted...

Tags: discussion, closing

Not sure how many have the same experience...

After writing a llllong answer, just shortly before clicking on "Post Your Answer", the OP deleted the question for whatever reason, and no more answers acceptable...

Didn't feel good... I wonder whether something could be done about that?

I used to see questions "put on hold", which is a more graceful way of deleting, and potentially can recover from the hold if a good answer (maybe comment) appears. Could the same rule apply to people deleting their own questions?

Sorry if there are already similar discussions here... I'm quite new to this site.

Comment: The purpose of putting a question on hold is to let the asker know that their question needs to be improved before they can get answers. If the asker needs to improve their own question, they only need to edit it. If they know that they need to improve their own open question, but don't know how just yet, usually the asker deletes their question, edits it, then undeletes it.

Comment: Related: [Self-deletion of question while typing answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29861) and [the posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/29861).

Comment: You could also ask OP in other of their posts: why did you deleted? and that you already had an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you still want to post your answer, there's nothing wrong with posting a new question of your own and then posting your answer to it. You probably shouldn't copy the original question word-for-word, but you can make a post that's asking essentially the same question as the original.