# Please don't delete your question

Tags: discussion, deletion, deleted-questions

This is not a question; it is simply that something happened that annoyed me and I wanted to record it.

Moments ago, I was typing an answer to

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3672909/8157

when all of a sudden the owner deleted the question and everything I had typed was lost. Everyone using a computer knows how annoying it is to waste time like that.

Generally speaking I don't like the "delete" feature on this website and use it only in extreme cases.

Comment: It happened to me many times. I was typing and then all of a suddent the answer is delted. There is nothing we can do about it. Sometimes they delete the question once answered. Which is disrecpectful also.

Comment: I feel like it has gotten worse lately.

Comment: I think I get it; you do have over 10K, so could see anything saved by the system. However, you had not posted your answer, it was still a "draft" when the question was deleted.

Comment: Why not posting your answer on some of the duplicates (if it adds something new). For example: [Prove $f $ is identically zero if $f(0)=0$ and $|f'(x)|\le|f(x)|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/750706), [$f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $|f'(x)|\le|f(x)|$ $\forall$ $x \in [0,1]$,$f(0)=0$.Show that $f(x)=0$ $\forall$ $x \in [0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1765676), [Prove that $f(x)\equiv0$ on $\left[0,1\right]$ if $f(0)=0$ and $|f'(x)|\le|f(x)|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/816021), etc.

Comment: As a side note, I searched for such posts using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%7Cf(x)%7C%5Cge%7Cf%27(x)%7C%24&p=1) and [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=$%7B%7Cf(x)%7C%5Cge%7Cf%27(x)%7C%7D$). See also: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: [Self-deletion of question while typing answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29861) (and the [posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/29861)),
[Is there a way to punish users for posting and then immediately deleting a question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13112) (and the [posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/13112)),
[On deleting vs. closing duplicate questions.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3338) (and the [posts linked there](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3338)), etc.

Comment: If this has gotten worse lately (Jonathan's comment), perhaps your 'question' should be pinned on Hot Meta Post?